# How do I determine why Google Analytics reports that pageviews per session went up temporarily?

Tags: google-analytics, page-views, session

Slightly strange thing happened on our site's blog recently - the pageviews per session jumped about 3 weeks ago to the same/above the number of sessions.

Then a few days ago that trend stopped and switched back to what it used to be, with pageviews dropping back into the sort of relationship we normally see.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be, or suggestions as to how I can dig into Google Analytics in more detail to find out what might have caused (and stopped) this?

[image]

Comment: Was there a shift in search terms used to find your site during that period? Was there a jump in particular referral sites? It could be that a hot topic came along that changed how your site performed for a period.

Answer (score 1):

This coincides with recent Panda update releases. If you did not bring major modifications to your site, this could explain that. Give it another week or two and if you don't see more changes, then there is no need to worry.

Comment: what panda updates were these and how did they cause people to view more pages per session? seems strange!

Answer (score 0):

Try to check:

a) is there any change in new users/recent users structure?

b) make an histogram to identify is change in pageviews per session was caused by churn of most valueable users or not?

c) which article is most popular as an entrance page? is it changed last time?

That steps could answer is it a change caused by Panda update, your site navigation or simply a topic you've mentioned at blog